# If two subspaces have the same basis are they equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

If they have the same basis, then surely they span the same vectors and so are equal?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that the all bases of a subspace V consist of the same number of vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2623924/proof-that-the-all-bases-of-a-subspace-v-consist-of-the-same-number-of-vectors)

Comment: @AnalysisJD not a duplicate, please read the question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the basis of two spaces $S_1 \text{ and } S_2$ is $b = \{v_1,...,v_n\}$

If $a\in S_1$ then $a = a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n \in S_2$ similarly if $a'\in S_2$ then $ a' = a_1'v_1+...+a_n'v_n\in S_1$

What can you conclude?